# How to accumulate values in a column and add the new earned value in a new column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data file looks like:

```
151
24
234
100
200
10
100
23
1
 ...
```

I want to have a new column in which each value in it is accumulated with previous value. For example `-151+0=151`, `24+151=175`, `234+175=409` so:
 output:

```
151
175
409
509
709
719
819
842
843
...
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 x <- c(151,24,234,100,200,10,100,23,1)
cumsum(x)
```

output::
[1] 151 175 409 509 709 719 819 842 843

This gave me the output as you want. Might help.

Answer (score 1):

look at the TTR package.

```
    library(TTR)
    x=c(151,24,234,100,200,10,100,23,1)
    y=runSum(x,n=2,cumulative=TRUE)
    y
```

Comment: I was tricked also by the way OP formulated it, but she wants the cumulate sum (exactly what `cumsum` does) and not the running sum of a number with the previous one. See the desired output.

Comment: runSum will do what she wants, except, the first point will be NA and not 151, a little cleaning will fix it. cumsum is probably the better way to go... just another method! take your pick!

Comment: @Justin Brousseau how can I have 151 instead of NA for first value?

Comment: The use of external packages should be avoided when basic functions do the job. For a simple task as this, using `TTR` would be silly. Furthermore, it can give the illusion that `R` can't make a very simple operation.

Comment: @Emily Just try `cumsum(x)`.

Comment: @nicola if instead of a colmn, I have a row then how should I change this to work?

Comment: is the row inside a data.frame? you can do cumsum(x[1,]) this will give you the first row.